# Same java getter for different types

Tags: java, methods

I need to write a java method to get specific information from an object. However, the object can either be of type A or of type B. Here is the part of my code :

```
class Composant{

int quantité;
static Composee pieceCompo;
static Simple pieceSimp;

public Composant(Composee piece, int nombre){
    pieceCompo = piece;
    quantité = nombre;
}

public Composant(Simple piece, int nombre){
    pieceSimp = piece;
    quantité = nombre;
}
public Composee getPiece(){
    return pieceCompo;
}
public Simple getPiece(){
    return pieceSimp;
}
public int getQuantite(){
    return quantité;
}}
```

When I write it like that it raises an error saying "Duplicate method". How can I get this to work?

Comment: `getCompo` and `getSimp` ? `getPieceCompo` and `getPieceSimp` ? That doesn't seem to be a hard problem

Comment: This is not posssible in Java. The return type is not part of the method signature. Therefore, we cannot have two method with same name and same (in this case: empty) parameter list, but different return types.

Answer (score 2):

As per [JLS, §8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> ...
>
> The signature of a method `m1` is a subsignature of the signature of a method `m2` if either:
>
> - `m2` has the same signature as `m1`, or
> - the signature of `m1` is the same as the erasure ([§4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)) of the signature of `m2`.
>
> Two method signatures `m1` and `m2` are *override-equivalent* iff either `m1` is a subsignature of `m2` or `m2` is a subsignature of `m1`.
>
> **It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with override-equivalent signatures in a class.**
>
> ...

This means that methods `public Composee getPiece()` and `Simple getPiece()` are override-equivalent. Since those two methods are in the same class, the compiler generates a compile-time error.

As was pointed out by [azro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7212686/azro) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053325/same-java-getter-for-different-types#comment123834818_70053325), we can instead write two separate getters `Composee getComposee()` and `Simple getSimple()`.

If `Simple` and `Composee` have a common supertype (e.g. `Piece`), we can write `Piece getPiece()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
public class Composant<T>{
    private final int quantite;
    private final T comp;

    public Composant(T comp,int quantite) throws BadTypeException {
        if(!(comp instanceof Composee) || !(comp instanceof Simple)) throw new BadTypeException("Can't create Composant with \"" + comp.getClass().getName() + "\" type object!");
        this.comp = comp;
        this.quantite = quantite;
    }

    public T getPiece(){
        return this.comp;
    }

    public int getQuantite(){
        return this.quantite;
    }
}
```

Exception is:

```
//  If you don't want to catch exception, change it to "RuntimeException"
class BadTypeException extends Exception{
    public BadTypeException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

And create like this:

```
    try {
        new Composant<Composee>(new Composee(),4);
    } catch (BadTypeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```